# Bootstrap 4 - How to create a table, which starts from second column?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I do have this HTML, but I am not able to do this:

- The `width` of the first column `Links available` should be same like the length of `Links available`, and the text shouldn't split this two words. It should be one line `Links available`
- On the column `Links available` only header is important, the cells below will not be used, so it could be hidden
- The buttons should have a `little bit space between next button`, and it should be like `inline`...

**What I want to, in visual:**

[image]

**My HTML:**

```html
           
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

           <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="col-xl">Links available:</th>
                      <th class="col-xl-auto">Category 1</th>
                      <th class="col-xl-auto">Category 2</th>
                      <th class="col-xl-auto">Category 3</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col-xl"></td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col-xl"></td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td class="col-xl"></td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-xl-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**if you would like to test my code, please use:** [codeply - Bootstrap snippets](https://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.1.3)

Comment: Can you include your current CSS showing what you have tried and what is working and what is not working.

Comment: can you explain briefly what are you want to do ?

Comment: no customized CSS, only that one from bootstrap. The reuslt looks like that one from `Run code snippet`. What I tried is about doingt with `col-xl-auto` etc. but no success.

Comment: @NishargShah I have updated my quesiton... please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove responsiveness column

**change**

> col-md-3

**to**

> col-3

Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th class="">Links available:</th>
            <th class="">Category 1</th>
            <th class="">Category 2</th>
            <th class="">Category 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>           
</table>
```

Second code using DIV

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Links available:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Category 1</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Category 2</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Category 3</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-md-3 mr-1">Small button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: run my code in full page so, you show your perfect answer

Comment: Thank you Nisharg. But there are still few open points like: 
- If I make my screen small, the `Links available` should not be splitted in two lines. Also the buttons should still have a little space between each other (in small page).

And also, in full page I would like to have the witdh of the cell `Links available` to the length of the text `Links available`.

Comment: can you explain your question in form of image because i don't understand what u want ? like split into two lines or have space in small screen or length of links available !

Comment: and second thing why u are using table for making this code ? you can simply using div and make responsive than table !

Comment: Your second answer was very helpful... Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a nested [Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). I recommend to read about this, so you can see examples of how to work with the **Bootstrap Grid System**. Even more, on **XS** (EXTRA SMALL) screens sizes I recommend to stack the categories vertically because of the little width you have available. You can check this  all on next example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
    <p class="my-1">Links available:</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 text-center bg-warning">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 my-1">Category 1:</div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 my-1">Category 2:</div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 text-center bg-warning">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 my-1">Category 3:</div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 my-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">B</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```